# Temporary tables and transactions in sql 2005

Tags: sql-server, transactions, temp-tables

I write app in c#. I use temporary tables inside transaction. My server is sql 2005. Is there any performance threat, I read somewhere that using temporary tables inside transactions should be avoided ( http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/temp_table_tuning_p1.aspx post at the bottom of the screen added at 2-24-2003 ).

Comment: Can you give an example of the operations that you're doing that require temporary tables? Personally I can't imagine why you would use them when you can store things in memory in c#

Comment: I have list of ids and want to use this list to filter outcomes of select statement. I put this list into temporary table and in WHERE part I filter out

Comment: thats what we do too. pass a list of Guids, pull it into a temp table and filter in dynamic sql statements (in sp) with exists.
No performance threat found in our application.
Works with thausends of rows.
But we dont use transactions cause we only take temp tables for our overview pages.
We use the temp tables for complex filter mechanisms of hierarchal data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy to test.

In one Query window run the following

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #T1(I INT)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (1)
```

Then in another Query Window run the same. You will find that there is no blocking.

So the claim in that tip that

> it would prevent others from executing
>   the same query, greatly hurting
>   concurrency and performance. In
>   effect, this turns your application
>   into a single-user application.

seems untrue.

Comment: I checked it also in my app, seems to work for many users at the same time

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the first row: "In general, temp tables should be avoided, if possible." Look at your application if is fast enough. Try to avoid a design based only on temp tables. Using of temp tables should be an exception inside of an application not a rule. Try to find an alternative design without increasing the cost ( time spent to build the new design ).
Look at this article to see how performance is influenced by the amount of data:
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/temp_tables_vs_variables_p1.aspx

Comment: It is not possible to avoid, within reasonable effort

Comment: For SQL 2005 with db created in 2005 ( not in compatible mode ) I don't see any reasons for blocking. The article is for 2000. The architecture had changed, and the performance cannot be bad only because you use a temp table. I am using ( not abusing ) and the performance is fine (the server have more than 50 databases ).